# Where is a tx located before finalized with the sequence number or locktime?

Tags: transactions, mempool, locktime, sequence

My understand, for a tx, before it finalized with the locktime, it can not go into mempool. But, which specified location is the tx to stay for waiting the locktime come. Similiar, for before the sequence number, where is the tx to stay for waiting?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tx is located with the person who created it. Nodes will not hold onto the transaction because it is not ready for the mempool. The only places a node will hold someone else's transaction is in the mempool or in the blockchain so a node will not store a non-final transaction anywhere.

It is up to the transaction creator to hold onto the transaction and not lose it until they can broadcast it after the lock time has passed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Are they the same situation for both locktime and sequence number? I ask that because the sequence number is original designed for hold tx in mempool, but some BIP modified it.

Comment: Most people just say locktime and sequence number are used to prevent the mining of a transaction until a certain date, but not tell at which step the prevention happen and where the tx to go after the prevention. About the locktime, the prevention is very clear that happen at check tx for entering mempool; but for sequence that not clear for me.

Comment: Some sequence numbers are allowed. The highest sequence number disables some things like RBF and relative lock times. That sequence number is allowed. The lower sequence numbers that allow those other features are also accepted. However anything lower than those will have the node reject the transaction as non-final.